# The constructor XMLSlideShow(FileInputStream) is undefined

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi

XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("slideshow.pptx")); is higlighted with error "The constructor XMLSlideShow(FileInputStream) is undefined".

The same line of code works fine in simpla java class in java perspective, but not in J2EE perspective with a servlet. Using apache poi jar.

Please help resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Apache POI certainly supports the [public XMLSlideShow(java.io.InputStream is) constructor](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XMLSlideShow.html#XMLSlideShow%28java.io.InputStream%29), as you can see from the [JavaDocs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XMLSlideShow.html#XMLSlideShow%28java.io.InputStream%29)

You need to make sure you're pushing the Apache POI jars and their dependencies out to your production environment, *and* ensuring that you don't have any old POI jars on your production classpath getting in the way